# Display & refresh an UpdatePanel after a postback from a different UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I've got a page with two UpdatePanels:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="ListUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
  <asp:ListView ... </asp:ListView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel id="DetailUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
..
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

There are postback controls in the ListView in the first panel. What needs to happen is when the page captures an event from the ListView, the page needs to switch modes. The code should display and then update the 2nd panel at that point. The command event will cause a property `PageMode` to be set to edit, then:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    ListPanel.Visible = PageMode == PageModes.List;
    EditPanel.Visible = PageMode == PageModes.Edit;
    if (PageMode == PageModes.Edit)
    {
        EditUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
    else
    {
        ListUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

But it's not working, I get this error: *ScriptResource.axd:868Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'ctl00_ctl11_DetailUpdatePanel'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.*

I would expect this, if my panels were set to automatic. I feel like there's something I'm not quite getting here. If a postback originates from inside an UpdatePanel, even though it's set to Conditional, is that control somehow tied to that UpdatePanel? Is there a way to get asp.net to "break out" of a given UpdatePanel, but not perform a full postback?

This came up b/c these both used to be in the same UpdatePanel, but I need to separate them because I have to implement logic to block submits in certain situations from the Details panel, which will be difficult to do if they're in the same UpdatePanel. I suspect it would work if I rendered them both all the time, and used CSS to hide the one I don't want the user to operate on for a given mode. Or alternatively, put them both in an outer UpdatePanel. But that seems like a lot of wasted bandwidth, I would hope there's a way to get this to work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Associate the Button on the first panel that causes the postback as a Asynctrigger on the other panel

Comment: Shouldn't manual control work just the same? I have a feeling I would get the same error.

Comment: I dont think, since updatepanle only does a partial rendering, it may not even send across the other panle with the request.

Answer (score 0):

When ASP.NET receives a request from an update panel, its response only includes that panel's contents (plus view state and event validation data). From [Partial-Page Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386573.aspx) on MSDN:

> An asynchronous postback behaves much
>   like a synchronous postback. All the
>   server page life-cycle events occur,
>   and view state and form data are
>   preserved. However, in the rendering
>   phase, only the contents of the
>   UpdatePanel control are sent to the
>   browser. The rest of the page remains
>   unchanged.

(I also recommend taking a look at the requests and responses yourself in Firebug, Fiddler, or another similar tool.)

If you're committed to using update panels (rather than jQuery or another client-side library) you're going to have to put the list and details inside a single panel.

Comment: Apparently I have a problem reading error messages... the answer was there all the time: <i>...then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.</i>. I wouldn't say I'm committed to using UpdatePanels, and I avoid them whenever possible, but the right tool for the right situation. I am already using jQuery for some validation and visual elements, though, but the logic that renders the forms is pretty complicated and I have no interest in replicating my object model on the client just to avoid an UpdatePanel!